# How to vertical allign buttons inside ul?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar with `<ul>` which contains some buttons. How can I center that buttons vertically inside `<ul>`?
They're sticked to the top now.
[image]

Please expand snippet full page.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</button></div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Register</button></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvbpOm)

Comment: how about adding ```padding-top:20px``` to ```.navbar-nav``` class?

Comment: switch to bootstrap V4 and you can do this easily

Comment: no, they are not sticked to the top. The ul IS the very same height as the li, the divs, and the buttons, as there's not padding there...

Comment: @Varinder sticks to bottom than

Comment: as @FacundoCorradini pointed out, the height of ```ul``` is exactly the as ```li``` so for vertical alignment, you may want to enter in equal ```padding-top``` and ```padding-bottom``` values, like so: ```.navbar-nav { padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; }```

Answer (score 0):

Put them inside the same list item:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Login</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register">Register</button></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will have to make them the same width.

https://codepen.io/wazz/pen/WMjMjx